# semantic ui react Setting dropdown value to state

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

how to have dropdowns selected value in state.here is my code iam getting value for name field but dropdown not working, can anyone find out what i am missing?

MyComponent.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component{
state={
   data:{
       name:'',
       subject:''  
   }
}

 onChange = e =>
    this.setState({
        data: { ...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    },()=>{
        console.log(this.state.data);
    }
    )

render(){
const {data}=this.state;
const subjects= [
              {text: '1',value: 'kannada'},
              {text: '2', value: 'english'},
              {text: '3',value: 'hindhi'}
            ]
return(
<div>
            <Input 
             name="name"
             onChange={this.onChange} 
             placeholder='Your name ...' 
            />
            <Dropdown 
             placeholder='Select Subject'
             name="subject"
             onChange={this.onChange}
             selection 
             options={subjects} 
             />
</div>

)
}
}
export default MyComponent;
```

how to have selected dropdown value in state?, iam getting changed value for name field but for dropdown not getting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value })
```

Add value prop to Dropdown

```
      render(
          const { value } = this.state;
        return(
         <Dropdown 
         placeholder='Select Subject'
         name="subject"
         onChange={this.handleChange}
         selection 
         options={subjects} 
         value={value}
         />)
       )
```

Comment: i tried that also adding value prop to dropdown, even though if i don't had value prop also for name field setting value correctly, incase of dropdown not working.

Comment: yeah but still your handle change function showing syntax error.

Comment: handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value }) this worked for me, now i have dropdown selected value in "this.state.value"

Answer (score 11):

If anyone is using react hooks and semantic ui react, this is how I got it to work, without having to create a separate change handler function for it.

```
const options = [
    { key: "1", text: "Speaker", value: "SPEAKER" },
    { key: "2", text: "Event Planner", value: "EVENT_PLANNER" }
  ];

const [values, setValues] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    userType: ""
  });

const onChange = (event, result) => {
    const { name, value } = result || event.target;
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

<Form.Dropdown
  placeholder="I am a.."
  name="userType"
  label="User Type"
  selection
  onChange={onChange}
  options={options}
  value={values.userType}
  />
```

What kept throwing me off was the 'result' that the onChange function takes as an argument. Since the options are stored as objects in an array, the correct way to access their values is with the 'result' and not 'event.target.'

Comment: What about the key. Is there any way to get the key to onChange event?

Comment: Thank you Sameer! The documentation is hidden a bit: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-controlled

Answer (score 2):

One more way to use DropDown in React Semantic. it worked perfectly for me.

```
const options = [
    { key: 'ex1', text: 'Example 1', value: 'Example 1' },
    { key: 'ex2', text: 'Example 2', value: 'Example 2' },
]
```

Method to set value

```
handleSelectChange=(e,{value})=>this.setState({stateValue:value})
```

In Form

```
<Form.Select fluid label='List Example' options={options}
placeholder='List Example' 
value={value} 
onChange={this.handleSelectChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form.Field also.
For more [information](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/).

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state={
      subject : ""
   }
}

handleChange = (e, result) => {
  const { name, value } = result;
  this.setState({
     [name]: value
    });
};

render() {
  const options = [
    { key: 'ex1', text: 'Example 1', value: 'Example 1' },
    { key: 'ex2', text: 'Example 2', value: 'Example 2' },
  ];

  return(
   <div> 
      <Form>
         <Form.Field 
            placeholder="Subject"
            name="subject"
            label="Subject"
            control={Dropdown}
            fluid
            selection
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
            value={this.state.subject}
         />
      </Form>     
   </div>
  );
}
```